# Launch ColdFusion from command line

Tags: command-line, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

**Is there a way to launch ColdFusion from the command-line?**

I am not talking about launching the CF and related services with the `net start` command.

I remember doing this in the past. Basically, running CF from the command-line offered two advantages:

1. You didn't need to keep it as a Service and either have it always launch at boot-up or have to deal with the Services Manager
2. (more importantly) It echoed back to the screen all kinds of messages, especially error messages, which were helpful when actively developing (because you didn't need to go dig in the ColdFusion log files to find them)

It is possible that I'm mis-remembering and that this hasn't been available since ColdFusion 5.0. Is it at all possible with ColdFusion 9?

***Update***: Environment: Multi-server configuration with JRun.

Comment: Is this what you are thinking of? http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/183/tn_18339.html

Comment: No, that's not it. I'll dig a bit deeper there, though.

Comment: CF ships with batch files to launch CF in a command window.  I believe that the URL Leigh provided shows that further down the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. In development, add the server to ColdFusion Builder, and all the messages you talk about will show up in the console tab.
2. Start ColdFusion from the command line. The instructions are slightly different per environment but basically you want to get to bin directory and issue `jrun start cfusion` or `coldfusion start` or something similar . Post your environment for more specifics.

Go to C:\JRun\bin and issue `jrun start cfusion`

Comment: @Al - Btw, I think #2 was in the kb article ;)

Comment: @Al - Just teasing because mine are just as bad. Good to have company ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your `ColdFusion9/bin` Folder you can find `stop.bat` and `start.bat`. Executing the latter gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: All I'm finding under `JRun\bin` is `adminstart.bat`.

Comment: In case of a multiserver configuration with JRun you can execute jrun_root\bin\jrun -start servername where servername represents the name of the instance you want to start

Comment: In ColdFusion10, the single-server directory is ColdFusion10/cfusion/bin and the commands are cfstop.bat and cfstart.bat